# How to get Updated currency exchange rate in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, datefilter, odoo-view

I have developed code to update currency exchange rate in odoo and it's successfully updated.

**Problem:** 
How to get currency list (only those currencies whose rate updated)

What I have done so far:

Created new action which render currency list view.

```
    <record id="action_currency_ex_rate" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Currency Exchange Rates</field>
        <field name="res_model">res.currency</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <!--<field name="domain">['|','|','|',('name','ilike','GBP'),('name','ilike','PLN'),('name','ilike','CZK'),('name','ilike','HUF')]</field>-->
        <field name="view_id" ref="base.view_currency_tree"/>
    </record>
```

I have tried to apply date filter in domain but it doesn't work.

```
<field name="domain">[('date','=',time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))]</field>
<field name="domain">[('date','=',context_today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))]</field>
```

How to apply current date filter ?